# Using MediaRecorder and SurfaceView together to capture and show video respectively

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

I have searched numerous topics on this but can't resolve my issue.

I have a SurfaceView that:

when loaded is magenta

when the green "record" button is pressed it shows the camera view, shows live camera feed and the button turns to red "stop"

when the red "stop" button is pressed the live camera feed stops and the button turns to green "record"

Here is some code:

**[VARIABLES]**

```
/* For the surface view */
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
SurfaceView surfaceView;

/* For saving the video to the device */
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;
// directory name to store captured images and videos
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "LapMaster";
private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
// Activity request code
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

/* For both */
Button cameraPreview;
Camera camera;
boolean previewing = false;
```

**[SET UP MEDIARECORDER AND SURFACE IN ONCREATE()]**

```
/*
 * Called when the page is loaded
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    cameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    cameraPreview.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    cameraPreview.setText("Record Video");

    //-------------------------------//
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    //-----------------------------------------------------------//
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(180000); // 180 seconds
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // approx. 5 megabytes

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    // Set the surfaceView so it appears on top, not behind the view
    surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    // Set the surfaceView background colour to magenta
    surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
```

**[THE BUTTON CODE TO USE MEDIARECORDER/SURFACE IN ONCREATE()]**

```
    cameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(previewing == false)
            {
                camera = Camera.open();
                if (camera != null)
                {
                    try 
                    {   
                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                        Log.i("1", "SetPreviewDisplay() OK");
                        camera.startPreview();

                        //------------//
                        camera.unlock();
                        //----------------------------//
                        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
                        //-----------------------------------------------------------//
                        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
                        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
                        Log.i("2", "Set sources OK");
                        //--------------------------------------//
                        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
                        //-----------------------------------//
                        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) == true)
                        {
                            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
                            String dest = fileUri.toString();
                            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(dest);
                        }
                        Log.i("3", "setOutPutFile() OK");
                        //-------------------------//
                        try
                        {
                            //--------------------//
                            mediaRecorder.prepare();
                            Log.i("4", "prepare() OK");
                            //------------------//
                            mediaRecorder.start();
                            Log.i("5", "start() OK");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                        previewing = true;
                        cameraPreview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        cameraPreview.setText("Stop");
                        Log.i("6", "setBackground(RED) and setText(Stop) OK");
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }           
            else if(camera != null && (previewing == true))
            {
                //-------------------------//
                try
                {
                    //-----------------//
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    Log.i("7", "mediaRecorder stop() OK");
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //---------------------//
                mediaRecorder.release();
                Log.i("8", "mediaRecorder release() OK");

                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
                Log.i("9", "camera stopPreview(), release() and set to null,  OK");
                previewing = false;
                cameraPreview.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                cameraPreview.setText("Record");
                Log.i("10", "setBackground(RED) and setText(Record),  OK");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**[SEPARATE "FILE" GENERATION CODE]**

```
/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) 
{
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) 
{
    // External sd card location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) 
    {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) 
        {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

When I run the application it loads up fine and I can press "record" to get the SurfaceView (and I assume MediaRecorder) working and I can press "stop" too to stop it. However if I press "record" nothing seems to happen and if I press it again it I get the usual "X has stopped working" message.

I have tried following:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFile(java.io.FileDescriptor)

But I just can't seem to get it to work properly.

**I think there are a few problems:

- Saving the file to SD?
- Not locking/closing/nulling the camera properly?

**

Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Edit:

My LogCat search for "OK" returns:

```
08-21 22:54:05.895: I/1(12901): SetPreviewDisplay() OK
08-21 22:54:06.486: I/2(12901): Set sources OK
08-21 22:54:06.496: I/3(12901): setOutPutFile() OK
08-21 22:54:06.506: I/6(12901): setBackground(RED) and setText(Stop) OK
08-21 22:54:09.148: I/8(12901): mediaRecorder release() OK
08-21 22:54:09.148: I/9(12901): camera stopPreview(), release() and set to null,  OK
08-21 22:54:09.148: I/10(12901): setBackground(RED) and setText(Record),  OK
```

So it seems to miss 4, 5 and 7?

Below is the LogCat (highlighted the "main" error):

```
08-23 12:08:29.835: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 19(0x636c69656e7473),sn(),family 0,flags 4
08-23 12:08:29.835: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
08-23 12:08:29.835: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 19(0x636c69656e7473),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
08-23 12:08:29.835: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
08-23 12:08:29.835: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-23 12:08:29.835: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
08-23 12:08:29.855: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 15(0x6373692e677374),sn(),family 0,flags 4
08-23 12:08:29.855: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
08-23 12:08:29.855: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 15(0x6373692e677374),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
08-23 12:08:29.855: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
08-23 12:08:29.855: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
08-23 12:08:30.105: D/libc(28017): [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
08-23 12:08:32.157: W/TextToSpeech(28017): speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
08-23 12:08:34.439: I/1(28017): SetPreviewDisplay() OK
08-23 12:08:34.840: I/2(28017): Set sources OK
08-23 12:08:34.880: I/3(28017): setOutPutFile() OK
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/LapMaster/VID_20140823_120834.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:852)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at net.learn2develop.lapmaster.TopGearLocationTracker$2.onClick(TopGearLocationTracker.java:263)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
08-23 12:08:34.880: W/System.err(28017):    ... 16 more
08-23 12:08:34.880: I/6(28017): setBackground(RED) and setText(Stop) OK
08-23 12:08:34.880: I/Choreographer(28017): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 12:08:41.667: E/MediaRecorder(28017): stop called in an invalid state: 4
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017): java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at net.learn2develop.lapmaster.TopGearLocationTracker$2.onClick(TopGearLocationTracker.java:291)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-23 12:08:41.667: W/System.err(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
08-23 12:08:41.677: W/System.err(28017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:41.677: D/MediaRecorder(28017): notifySurfaceConnected
08-23 12:08:41.677: I/8(28017): mediaRecorder release() OK
08-23 12:08:41.677: I/9(28017): camera stopPreview(), release() and set to null,  OK
08-23 12:08:41.677: I/10(28017): setBackground(RED) and setText(Record),  OK
08-23 12:08:44.871: W/System.err(28017): java.io.IOException: setPreviewTexture failed
08-23 12:08:44.871: W/System.err(28017):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:693)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at net.learn2develop.lapmaster.TopGearLocationTracker$2.onClick(TopGearLocationTracker.java:237)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
08-23 12:08:44.881: W/System.err(28017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:44.891: I/Choreographer(28017): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-23 12:08:48.675: W/CameraBase(28017): An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0
08-23 12:08:48.675: W/dalvikvm(28017): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41650e18)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): Process: net.learn2develop.lapmaster, PID: 28017
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:549)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:424)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:475)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at net.learn2develop.lapmaster.TopGearLocationTracker$2.onClick(TopGearLocationTracker.java:232)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
08-23 12:08:48.685: E/AndroidRuntime(28017):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 12:08:50.947: D/Process(28017): killProcess, pid=28017
```

Comment: An exception must be being thrown and caught from mediaRecorder.prepare();  Can you post any exceptions you are receiving please?

Comment: Thanks for your response Craig. I have added the LogCat to my question. The main error (exception) is bolded and is near the bottom. I will add the try/catch clause (exception) to prepare(), test it and see what happens. I also need to sort out setting up a directory/file to save the video.